# Raspberry Pi 3 Mono C# Bluez

Tags: c#, mono, bluetooth-lowenergy, raspberry-pi3, bluez

Using **Raspberry Pi 3** and it's built-in BLE chip I was able to install a Bluez nodejs example app to make my Raspi3 a **BLE Peripheral**,  and I was able to read and write to the Gatt and echo information to my **BLE Central Client**.

However,  now that I am trying to replace the nodejs **BLE Perhipheral** solution on my Raspi3 to use **Mono.BlueZ**, and **dbus-sharp** mono libraries to make a mono app that would make my Raspi3 a **BLE Perhipheral**.

Immediately, I am running into issues compiling

I am compiling in VS 2017 RC as a 3.5 project.
dbus-sharp project I am trying to compile:
https://github.com/brookpatten/dbus-sharp 
[image]

Supporting Mono Bluez file that I will eventually use:
https://github.com/brookpatten/Mono.BlueZ

1. Is there something that I need to do to actually compile the project?
2. Is there any additional documentation or examples of how to get this compiled?

Comment: this question doesn't have enough information to be able to answer, please show the piece of code that the compiler is whining about

Answer (score 0):

I'm also trying to work with this project.

I managed to build and debug it like this (on Debian 8):

I installed the latest version of Mono (5.0) and could build the project by just typing msbuild in the project root. It also works from within VS Code and I can also debug the project after creating launch.json and tasks.json files.

However, when I debug Mono.BlueZ.Console, it hangs right away on this line:

var manager = GetObject (Service, ObjectPath.Root);

Comment: I had this problem too, but after upgrading (http://helloraspberrypi.blogspot.com/2015/04/install-latest-version-of-mono-and.html) to the most recent version of mono, I no longer hung at that line.

Comment: That's weird. It didn't even build until I installed the latest version of mono but with v5.0 it still hangs.